# jQuery: How to select closest parent without class or id? (ERROR: parent is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***I had a typo in my code :)***

---

Let's say my html code looks like this:

```
 <a href="/">
    <div id="nonUniqueID" class="uniqueClass">
 </a>
```

and what I am trying to do is select anchor tag, using jQuery:

```
  var $x = ('.uniqueClass').parent();
  $x.addClass('uniqueAnchorClass');
```

which throws me an error that apparently 'parent() is not a function'. I am unable to use parents() because then it would select all parents and add my new class to them. I was also trying to select it like this:

```
  var $x = ('.uniqueClass').parent().getAttribute('href');
  $x.addClass('uniqueAnchorClass');
```

but it throws same error as well. Does anyone know any other way or maybe I am doing smth wrong?

Comment: Typo: `('.uniqueClass').parent();` should be `$('.uniqueClass').parent();`

Comment: You're welcome! By seeing the number of downvotes perhaps you could delete your question..

Answer (score -1):

Forgetting  **$** in `var $x = **$**('.uniqueClass').parent();`